# Performance impact due to Sp Size in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Hi it might sound foolish but since I had came across two such situations I have to ask the question here

I had an sp which has 6 different IF blocks , only a single block will get executed whenever sp called from the page

there are Four common tables which were used in all six IF blocks the change was only the where condition in each block

So what I had done is created a Temp Table at the beginning of the sp , inserted the needed columns from all Four tables to the Temp table and used this table in all six IF blocks with different where conditions

Now when I executed the sp it actually showed me improvement in performance as compared to earlier

The only thing I had done is reduce the size of sp by eliminating same code and using a temp table

Now my question is out of the six blocks only one will get executed every time the sp is called so what difference does it make to reduce size of sp

Comment: It would help greatly if you posted both versions of the SP...

Answer (score 2):

You ask a pretty open question, so I'll provide a pretty open answer until you post the two versions of the stored procedures as I requested in the comments. Here you go:

Usually the size of a stored procedure is not related strongly to its execution duration. I could write you a very short stored procedure that takes forever to execute and I could write you a very long stored procedure that executes in no time.

What matters more in terms of execution time is the amount of data you work on and whether that amount of data can be worked on efficiently (using an index, by reducing the amount of data in the first place, etc).

So my guess is that while you optimized your stored procedure "by eliminating same code" you also made the SP access the data in a more efficient way.